# Gatsby TypeError - Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to display results from a JSON file and keep getting the error below and not sure why. The query works fine in GraphiQL.

Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

    const SecondPage = () => (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query StaticDataQuery {
            allStaticdataJson {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <div>
            <h1>Graphql test:</h1>
            <p>{data.allStaticdataJson.edges.node.id}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    )

    export default SecondPage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are expecting `allStaticdataJson` to return an array of edges. If that's the case, you need to iterate over them to access each node's id.

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

    const SecondPage = () => (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query StaticDataQuery {
            allStaticdataJson {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <div>
            <h1>Graphql test:</h1>
            {data.allStaticdataJson.edges.map(edge => {
              <p>{edge.node.id}</p>
            })}
          </div>
        )}
      />
    )

    export default SecondPage
```